# I'm getting UnicodeDecodeError when trying to load a JSON file into a dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

So, I'm using the following code to get pandas to read my JSON text file-

```
f = open('C:/Users/stans/WFH Project/data.json') 
data = json.load(f)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])
f.close()
```

Once I execute the cell, I get

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position
> 1535: character maps to

I used the above coding for a smaller sample of JSON data and it worked. But, since I updated the file to include a much larger sample, I get that error.

I verified that the JSON format is correct, and I also tried in the open statement-

```
encoding='utf-8'
```

and

```
errors='ignore'
```

Both produced value errors. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: what's the format of your JSON?  a list of dict?  if so try`pd.DataFrame()` on parts of list by using slices to find the offending unicode character

Comment: Hey Rob. Yes, the JSON was a list of dict. Although the above decode functions didn't work, I then tried   encoding = 'unicode_escape', which worked, and I was finally able to load the JSON file into a dataframe.